# VSTS Dashboard: How to chart all user stories under a specific feature?

Tags: azure-devops

this seems like something that should be possible but I can't figure out how to make it happen.  In my dashboard I would like a chart that shows the states of all the user stories that have a specific feature as the parent.

It seems like the chart only works on flat work item queries and I can't figure out a way to create a flat query that has all the stories with a specific parent.

Anyone know a good way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marina stated the chart only supports flat queries.

But I would suggest another workaround: Use tags or a separate area to mark the work items under the feature and create a flat query based on those. That way you don't have to change the query when you add work items to the feature.

EDIT: You still have to set the tag/area manually to the story, when you add it to the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, chart can only created by Flat list of work items Type (not work items and direct links Type and Tree or work items Type).

So the work around is that you can query the user stories belong to a certain feature by Tree or work items Type, and then create a new query for the user stories you find in first step (such as query by ID, title etc).

Comment: Hi Marina, I didn't know there was a way to nest queries, could you add how that is done?

Comment: I meant you need to use two queries. One for query the work items belong to a certain feature. The other for query the work items as the first step by flat list, and then add a chart to dash board.

Answer (score 1):

You can custom widget by using extension and display result in a [TreeView control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/ui-controls/treeviewo).

Regarding widget extension, you can refer to: [Add a dashboard widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget)

Other extension samples: [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)  (widgets)